# es2015 arrow functions, fetch and this

Tags: ecmascript-6, this, arrow-functions

everyone

I have constructor in class that looks like

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([])
    };
    let url = Config.baseUrl + "/strains";
    let request = {
      headers: {
        "X-API-Key": Config.apiKey
      }
    };
    fetch(url, request)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        if (responseData.data) {
          let strains = responseData.data.map((strain) => {
            return {
              name: strain.name,
              image: strain.image
            };
          });
          this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(strains)
          };
          console.dir(this.state);
        }
      });
  }
```

What I can't get working is this.state assignment inside fetch callback.
I'm new to es2015. Read about arrows functions and if I understand it right it should work just fine.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: From the debugger.
I use WebStorm and React-Native. 

Local:
  > this = global
Closure
  > _this = CannabisReports0

Comment: I'd put a debugger statement inside the fetch callback. My assumption is that you are inspecting the component before the response was received. In general, making an async request in the constructor doesn't make sense for React components. You should be doing this in another lifecycle methods (such as `componentDidMount`).

Comment: Are you debugging the Babel transpiled output, or  native classes, because Babel renames things. That said, shouldn't that be `this.setState`? Just assigning `this.state` will not tell React to kick off a render.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody.

this.setState did the thing.